# How to properly answer an "Age" field in a form?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following is the most correct to use?

> Age: 13 years old
>
> Age: 13 years
>
> Age: 13

Comment: On a "form" all they expect is the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless one is filling out a form to register an infant for something, the number alone would be adequate. If for an infant, you might need to say 6 months, 18 months, etc. 
With regard to your school project interview, you would first review your project requirements to see if they specify a format for the age. If they do not, write it as 24 years, 48 years, etc.

Comment: If I were filling out the form and the box related to someone else I'd write "years" after any age under 30 in most cases just in case they counted the father of my grandchild as a child himself!

Comment: Thank you for helping me! But, now, what if I was describing someone else, not necessarily in a form? I have a school assignment in which I need to interview a person and, before writing down the answers, I need to write down its information, such as name, age, gender etc., just like if it was some sort of document. How would I fill the "age" in this case?  Thanks (again) in advance!